# Python Numerical Error Arising in Series of Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm attempting to write a script to parse a very large data file with information on location and time, and store that information in an array (i.e. a list of lists), however, for some reason my code is writing the same numbers across multiple sub-lists.

```
# Import data from inputFile into list
with open(r"C:\..file.dat") as inputFile:
    inputList = list(inputFile)

totalSegs = 775
totalPrds = 938

stressPrd = 1
segNum = 1
testList = []
masterList = []

while stressPrd <= totalPrds: #build a list of times
    testList.append(0)
    stressPrd += 1

while segNum <= totalSegs: #build a list of locations
    masterList.append(testList) #list of time periods by location
    segNum += 1

stressPrd = 1
segNum = 1

for inputItem in inputList: #read data from file and write to lists
    if inputItem != '\n'
        inputItem = inputItem.split()
        if int(inputItem[3]) == int(segNum):
            testVar = float(masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1])
            testVar += float(inputItem[6])
            masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1] = testVar
        else:
            segNum += 1
            if segNum <= totalSegs:
                testVar = float(masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1])
                testVar += float(inputItem[6])
                masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1] = testVar
            else:
                segNum = 1
                stressPrd += 1
                testVar = float(masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1])
                testVar += float(inputItem[6])
                masterList[segNum - 1][stressPrd - 1] = testVar
```

What should happen is that the data for the same location (segNum) from the same time (stressPrd) is summed and stored in a sublist organized by stressPrd, and then that list for a given location across time is stored by segNum in the parent list. What is happening, however, is that the script instead sums all data across all locations for a given time (stressPrd), and that sum is stored in every location sublist.

I've tried inserting some print statements to track what's happening to multiple sub-lists simultaneously, and they all start tallying the same sum at the same time. My variables segNum and stressPrd both seem to increment correctly, and as near as I can tell my If statements are executing correctly, so I'm having trouble figuring out the source of the problem.

As a very simplified example of the result I want:

```
Data:
Loc    Time1    Time2
A      6        1
A      2        2
B      2        3
C      5        4
C      1        1

Result:
[[8,3],[2,3],[6,5]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than try to debug the particular problem occurring here, I'd strongly recommend switching to pandas if you're working with tabular data. This is a pretty straightforward problem there:

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [18]: datatable = """Loc    Time1    Time2
A      6        1
A      2        2
B      2        3
C      5        4
C      1        1"""

In [19]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(datatable), sep=" +", engine="python")

In [20]: df.groupby("Loc").sum()
Out[20]:
     Time1  Time2
Loc
A        8      3
B        2      3
C        6      5
```

If you want the particular format you specified, it's easy enough to pull that out at the end too:

```
In [28]: [list(v[1].values) for v in df.groupby("Loc").sum().iterrows()]
Out[28]: [[8, 3], [2, 3], [6, 5]]
```